# Spring boot to load list of packages from properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, package, spring-vault

I have project setup using Spring boot that loads individual components on startup. Each individual packages contain its own datasource, processes, etc. I can simply use this and it works fine

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
    "com.package1",
    "com.package2",
    "com.package3"
})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args)        
    }
}
```

But currently, the number of indiviual projects are getting bigger. Is it possible to put the list of the components / packages to scan in an external properties file or spring vault? I'm not sure how to retrieve it, and is it possible to retrieve the properties before the boot?

---

Edit:

Currently I tried this:

```
@Import(AppConfig.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args)        
    }
}


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {$app.packages})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AppConfig {
}

//in my properties file
app.packages = ["com.package1","com.package2","com.package3"]
```

but its not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on right track but couple of minor mistakes, specify the packages by common separated in `yml` or `properties` file

```
app.packages = com.package1,com.package2,com.package3
```

Then use Spring Expression Language in `@ComponentScan` annotation

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"${app.packages}"})
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a static string constant. I tried following and it is working.

ScanBasePackageTestApplication  is in 3rd package other than "test.packageOne, test.packageTwo" packages. Then I tried to autowire single class from each of test.packageOne and test.packageTwo into class from main package and it worked fine.

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = PackagesScanMetaData.PACKAGES_TO_SCAN)
public class ScanBasePackageTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ScanBasePackageTestApplication.class, args);
    }

}

public class PackagesScanMetaData {
    public static final String PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "test.packageOne, test.packageTwo";

}
```

In this case you can manage all the to be scanned package list in `PackagesScanMetaData`  class. Hope this helps.